# complex iteration logic in hogan js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, hogan.js

I'm trying to learn expressjs, I have a controller which queries a db, and returns a JSON object which looks something like this:

```
[ { _id: 58cb851721c1c107ab436686,                                                                                                                             
   title: 'some title',                                                                                                                        
   content: 'this is content' },                                                                                                           
  { _id: 58cb856321c1c107ab436688,                                                                                                                             
   title: 'ah yes',                                                                                                                                           
   content: 'more title and contents' } 
   ...
   ...
]
```

What I now want to do is display every element in the array in a MDL card layout. So, If the above json object has 20 objects, there should be 20 cards each showing values of their respective `_id`, `title` and `content` properties. To do that I'll have to use a for loop somewhat like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    <span> {{ data[i]._id }} </span> </br>
    <span> {{ data[i].title }} </span> </br>
    <span> {{ data[i].content }} </span> </br>
  }
```

This is clearly very easy with something like ejs because it allows loop logic inside the templates. But I have no clue how to do that in HoganJS's lack of a proper documentation clearly isn't helping. I've searched a lot on the interwebs with no avail. Currently I'm rendering the template like:

`res.render('index');`

Is it possible to do this in hogan, how? or I'll need to do some gymnastics in my routes?

Answer (score 1):

*Hogan.js was developed against the **mustache** test suite, so everything that holds true for templates as specified, is also the case for hogan.js.*

Check https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html

Something like this should work:

```
var obj = {
  data: [{ 
    _id: 58cb851721c1c107ab436686,                                                                                                                             
    title: 'some title',                                                                                                                        
    content: 'this is content'
  }, {
    _id: 58cb856321c1c107ab436688,                                                                                                       
    title: 'ah yes',                                                                                                                                           
    content: 'more title and contents'
  },  
  ...
  ]};
```

and the template:

```
{{#data}}
  <span>{{_id}}</span>
  <span>{{title}}</span>
  <span>{{content}}</span>
{{/data}}
```

Comment: So I tried doing something like `obj = { 'data': [{...}, {...}...]}`, then i pas this to a list like `res.render('/', {list: obj.data})` where list is used in place of `{{ #data}}` but for some reason it still isn't working, it says 'cannot read property data from undefined' think I might have to post another question regarding this.

Comment: The problem there seems to be that somewhere in your code the object you are trying to use and has a `data` property is undefined. Yeah, you should add the whole code.